# To enhance the way of the getting highest occurrence of an element in a array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, treemap

I got the below question during an interview.

Question:
You need to find the most frequent element in an array. The array consists of integers. For example, if you have a sequence of such integers: 1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2, the solution will be the string:

The winner is number 3, its frequency of occurrence is 6

And the answer to this question was being improved during the interview session.

Below is the source code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class RepeatedElement {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2};
    
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    
    int len = arr.length;
    
    int count = 1;
    
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    
    int i=0;
    while(i < len) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++) {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j]) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }else {
                break;
            }
        }
        map.put(arr[i], count);
        count = 1;
        i++;
    }
    
        
    int max = 0;
    int key = 0;
    for(int k:map.keySet()) {
        int temp = map.get(k);
        
        if(temp>max) {
            max = temp;
            key = k;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Winner is: "+key+" and it's occurrences: "+max);
}
}
```

I also searched for other similar questions in stackoverflow as well. I just want to understand whether this is a good approach to this problem. I believe code explains better the approach I tried. At the same, I am curious to know about time and space complexity which will provide bigger inputs. Folks, kindly provide your ideas to improve this code if it has some flaws. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really see how your 'while(i<len)` loop can work. It will only count consecutive numbers with the `break` in there. Then the `Map.put` will overwrite the value of a previous entry.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the compute function from [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to simplify the first loop to something like this:

```
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map.compute(arr[i], (k,v) -> v == null ? 1 : v+1);
    }
```

Alternatively, if you're open to 3rd party libraries you could use the [Bag](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/docs/guide.md#-bag) type from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), and replace the whole method with the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2};
    MutableBag<Integer> bag = Bags.mutable.of(arr);
    ObjectIntPair<Integer> top = bag.topOccurrences(1).getFirst();
    System.out.println("Winner is: "+top.getOne()+" and it's occurrences: "+ top.getTwo());
}
```

There is even a [PrimitiveBag](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/docs/guide.md#primitive-bags) type to avoid the boxing of the `int`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2};
    MutableIntBag bag = IntBags.mutable.of(arr);
    IntIntPair top = bag.topOccurrences(1).getFirst();
    System.out.println("Winner is: "+top.getOne()+" and it's occurrences: "+ top.getTwo());
}
```

Comment: OP just wants to know how to solve the problem efficiently, probably not to know how to use different libraries.

Comment: Hi @SomeDude, thanks for the comment, that's exactly why I suggested using map.compute at the top of my answer. Eclipse Collections is worth mentioning because not only is the code more concise, but data structure implementations themselves are very efficient, and they have a lot of benchmarks to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 1):

From this statement  `map.put(arr[i], count);` in your code , it seems you don't recognize the fact that you can use the existing value to update an existing key in your map. That is why you seem to be counting the element by iterating the keys all over.
You could use `map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) + 1)` to update the key's count as soon as you see the key again.

Also you don't need to iterate over the map's keySet again to get maximum frequency, you could get it while you are populating the map itself.

Code will be :

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int[] arr = {1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2};
      Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
      int max = 1;
      int maxKey = arr[0];
      for ( int k : arr ) {
          map.put(k, map.getOrDefault(k, 0) + 1);
          if ( map.get(k) > max ) {
              max = map.get(k);
              maxKey = k;
          }
      }
      System.out.println("Winner is: "+ maxKey+" and it's occurrences: "+max);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a **sort**: there is no need for introducing a time complexity >= O(NLogN)

There is also no need to use a **TreeMap**. Use a **HashMap** instead to reduce the get or put operations to constant instead of log(N).

You can **coalesce** the two loops into one.

**Complexity** of solution below:

1. The time complexity in the code below is O(N).
2. Space Complexity is O(N).

*Use the [map.compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) (Java 8+)* to increment existing frequency count. This way you do NOT need to

1. firstly get the existing value,
2. check if it exists and and if it does increment or set it to 1 if it does not.

You could *use the [map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) (Java 8+)* operation as well.

Examples of both *merge* and *compute* are illuminated in the code below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MostFrequentElementInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2 };

    int len = arr.length;


    int mostFreqKey = arr[0];

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int elem : arr) {
        // you can use any of the 3:
        int newVal = map.compute(elem, (K, oldVal) -> oldVal == null ? 1 : oldVal + 1  );
        // int newVal = map.merge(elem, 1, (oldVal, valWhichIs1) -> oldVal + valWhichIs1);
        // int newVal = map.merge(elem, 1, Integer::sum);
        if (map.get(mostFreqKey) < newVal) {
            // this is the new frequently occurring element
            mostFreqKey = elem;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    System.out.println("Winner is: " + mostFreqKey + " and it's occurrences: " + map.get(mostFreqKey));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hash table to keep counts for each integer. Both the Space and Time complexity would be O(N). Iterate through each element in the array and insert it in the hash map with array[i] as key and value as 1 if it don't exists. And when you see that its already there just increment the value. Then after this an another loop to get the maximum valued key.

Your solution is similar but notice that sorting is unnecessary when you are using the Map object. And when you are taking a Map then there is no need to find the similar elements from the current index. Your solution would make the interviewer feel that you don't completely understand the concept of maps. And also notice that sorting would make your approach to be O(N logN). From interview's point of view I'm sure that the question wanted to test your understanding about hash tables.

Here's my approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2};
 
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
            map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(arr[i], 1);
        }
    }
 
    int max = 0;
    int key = 0;
    int temp;
    for(int k: map.keySet()) {
        temp = map.get(k);
 
        if(temp > max) {
            max = temp;
            key = k;
        }
    }
 
    System.out.println("Winner is: "+key+" and it's occurrences: "+max);
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. There are multiple ways to do this but in my opinion the simpler it is the better it is. Keep the code simple and use the things that you are most comfortable with because those may invite more questions during the interviews. I'm good with simple get put contains and people have used compute and getOrDefault etc which seems better to write.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the most optimized way I could come up with. Not only did it shortens the code a lot it also process the information with the same time complexity. Not that it matters for complexity, with this approach we are only iterating once one data structure.

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2};
Map<Integer, Integer> occurrenceMap = new HashMap<>();
int winnerNumber = -1;
int maxOccurrence = 0;
for (int i : arr) {
    if (occurrenceMap.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum) > maxOccurrence) {
        winnerNumber = i; maxOccurrence = occurrenceMap.get(i);
    }
}
System.out.format("The winner is number " + winnerNumber
        + ", its frequency of occurrence is " + maxOccurrence + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

The presented code is a bit complicated as it sorts the input array, then counts the frequencies in the sorted map using nested loops, and then finds the max frequency in the map.

If a map is used to count the frequencies, pre-sorting is redundant.  Getting rid of it would allow to remove the most complex part `O(N log N)` of the initial algorithm.

Also, the value with the max frequency should be identified immediately while iterating the input array.

Next, since Java 8 `Map` has such methods as [`Map::compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to facilitate modification of values in the map, which is increment in this case.

That being said, the code may be refactored as:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 3, 2};
    
    Map<Integer, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    Integer mostFrequent = null;
    Integer highestFreq = null;
    
    for (int x : arr) {
        Integer currFreq = freqMap.compute(x, (k, v) -> null == v ? 1 : v + 1);
        // Integer currFreq = freqMap.merge(x, 1, Integer::sum); // merge example
        if (null == mostFrequent || currFreq > highestFreq) {
            mostFrequent = x;
            highestFreq = currFreq;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Winner is %d and its occurrences %d%n", mostFrequent, highestFreq);
}
```